# Join two RDDs, one of which has only keys and no values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Given two large RDDs, `a` with a set of `(key, value)` pairs and `b` with only `keys`, what would be the best way to join them such that `a` keeps only those rows that match the keys of `b`?

More specifically, this is what I want to do:

```
val a: RDD[(Int, Double)] = ...
val b: RDD[Int] = ...
val c: RDD[(Int, Double)] = a.myFilterJoin(b)
```

where `c` contains only the rows of `a` that match the keys in `b`, and we can assume that `a` contains only unique keys. Is there anything like `myFilterJoin` available?

Note that if `b` would be small enough, I could simply broadcast it as a set and then use it as a filter on `b`. But let's assume `b` is large enough for this broadcast to be prohibitively expensive.

What I usually do is to add a dummy variable to `b` such that `b` gets the form of `(key, dummy)` to be able to do the join, and then I remove the dummy variable in a map. But this seems quite hacky and I was wondering if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to ShemTov's answer but preserving type safety by using **Datasets** instead of **DataFrames**.
*(PS: I would recommend you to just use **Datasets** instead of **RDDs**)*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext
import spark.implicits._

val a = sc.parallelize(List((1 -> 0.0), (2 -> 3.3), (3 -> 5.5), (5 -> 10.11)))
val b = sc.parallelize(List(2, 3, 4, 5))

val c = b.toDS.joinWith(a.toDS, $"value" === $"_1", "inner").map {
  case (_, (key, value)) => key -> value
}.rdd
```

Answer (score 2):

it sound like you should use inner join:

```
  import spark.implicits._

  val a: DataFrame = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1, 2.5), (2, 4.4), (3, 2.1))).toDF("keyA", "value")
  val b: DataFrame = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(3, 5, 1)).toDF("keyB")

  val c = a.join(b, $"keyA" === $"keyB", "inner").drop("keyB")

  c.show()

+----+-----+
|keyA|value|
+----+-----+
|   1|  2.5|
|   3|  2.1|
+----+-----+
```

and if you want return c to be RDD[(Int,Double)], you can use:

```
  val d = c.rdd.map(row => (row.get(0).asInstanceOf[Int], row.get(1).asInstanceOf[Double]))
```